# How to set margin of item in flexbox?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to set the `margin` of items in a flexbox to `2%`.
But if I set each `margin` to `2%`, they don't have same length visually.

I want to set distance to 2% between each item.
Also, i wanna set 2% distance from border of flexbox.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 800px;
}

#left {
  width: 550px;
  height: inherit;
  float: left;
}

#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.item {
  width: 47%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="flexbox">
      <div class="item">div1</div>
      <div class="item">div2</div>
      <div class="item">div3</div>
      <div class="item">div4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by 'each margin don't have same length visually'? From what I saw from your example you are setting left margin 2% for each `.item` and all of them have the occupy the same width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is using nested `div` and apply the margin within those divs, this ways you can have more controls over margin. Since you are using flexbox, you can use `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` to distribute your divs instead of using width and height.

You can try this:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#wrap {
  width: 800px;
  background:#ece8e8;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#left {
  width: 550px;
  height: inherit;
  float: left;
  background:#b8b8b8;
}

#flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*margin-left: 2%;*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.item {
  /*width: 47%;*/
  /*height: 200px;*/
  /*margin-right: 2%;*/
  background: grey;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item>div {
    background: #454444;
    margin: 2%;
    height: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(1)>div,
.item:nth-child(2)>div{
  margin-right: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="flexbox">
      <div class="item"><div>div1</div></div>
      <div class="item"><div>div2</div></div>
      <div class="item"><div>div3</div></div>
      <div class="item"><div>div4</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```